# Multicast CoAP request doesn't reach the server?

Tags: openthread

I have a problem with the CoAP multicast requests. When I use the "multicast" address instead of the "unicast", I can ping the server but the CoAP request doesn't reach the server. I used the same request, I just changed the address. Any suggestion?

Comment: Is the server (software) actually listening on that multicast address? Are you on the same L2 network, or are there routers in between? Do you see the packets reaching the server (with your favorite packet sniffer)? Do you see anything in the server logs? Do you see a request being sent back?...

Comment: 1- i have only three nodes, so one client and two servers , they are in the same network. they are subscribed in the multicast address. i used a code like the one posted by (nordic semiconductor).